# Method that inserts a node at the end of a list, using the tail reference Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am currently trying to write a method `insertEnd` that inserts a node at the end of a list, using the tail reference. As I am still learning about it, I do not know how I can approach this. If you have any suggestions or solutions, please could you let me know as it will help me greatly.

```
package lib;

public class LinkedList {
private Node head;
private Node tail;

public LinkedList(Node h){
    head = h;
}
public Node getHead(){
    return head;
}
public Node getTail(){
    return tail;
}

public void setHead(Node n){
    head = n;
}

    public void insertEnd(Node newNode){

    }
```

```
public class ListApp {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Node n4 = new Node("green", null);
        Node n3 = new Node("orange", n4);
        Node n2 = new Node("blue", n3);
        Node n1 = new Node("red", n2);





package lib;

public class Node {
private String item;
private Node nextItem;

public Node(String str, Node n){
    item = str;
    nextItem = n;
}
public String getItem(){
    return item;
}
public void setItem(String str){
    item = str;
}
public Node next(){
    return nextItem;
}
public void setNext(Node n){
    nextItem = n;
}

public String getHead(){
    return item;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution:

```
public void insertEnd(Node newNode){
    newNode.setNext(null);
    if (tail == null) {
        tail = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        tail.setNext(newNode);
        tail = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there when i tried this it brings up an error on line 2 and 7 saying "next cannot be resolved or isn't a field". How can i go about to correct this?
many thanks

Comment: @Abdul OK, you've not posted class Node, so I had to guess the name of the link field

Comment: @Abdul OK, the field is private, so we need to use method setNext()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Node, holds a reference to next,

```
public class Node<E>{
  private E ele;
  private Node<E> next;
```

P.S: Java already does have the LinkedList implemented for our convenience.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your time. However as I am still learning i have been asked to follow this rule.
    public void insertEnd(Node newNode) {
    }